# XCode5 XTC link problems with target object being tested

Tags: linker, xcode5, xctest

In full disclosure, I am new to IOS/ObjectiveC/Xcode.  I am setting up a testing suite for unit testing using the built in XCode5 XTC library.  I am having a fundamental problem with linking test code to the object I am testing.  I looked all over the WEB and there are many examples on how to copy and past code into your XTC testing objects but I could not locate examples on how to setup the test code so that it could link against the objects you were testing.  Where could I look to properly include the link locations in XCode5 project properties?

Below is a short snippet of the test code...

```
#import <XCTest/XCTest.h>
#import “ObjectA.h”

@interface SimpleTest : XCTestCase
@end
@implementation SimpleTest
- (void)testExample
{
    ObjectA *objectA;

    objectA = [[ObjectA alloc] init];

    XCTAssertTrue(ObjectA != nil, @“ObjectA is nil!");
}
@end
```

Here are the errors:

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
    "_OBJC_CLASS_$ObjectA”, referenced from: objc-class-ref in SimpleObject.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    "_OBJC_CLASS_$ObjectA”, referenced from: objc-class-ref in SimpleObject.o**

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that you have the right target dependency?

In your targets 'Build Phases' tab you should see your main project target listed under 'Target Dependencies'

When I have linking problems I also use Xcode's preferences -> locations to find and delete the current derived data directory and run a clean build.